Unable to resolve tensorflow model weight bin file in react native
`const loadModel = async () => {
const temperatureModel = await tf.loadLayersModel(
bundleResourceIO(temperatureLSTM, modelWeight)
).catch((e)=>{
console.log("error: ",e)
})
return temperatureModel
}
useEffect(() => {
loadModel()
}, []);`
Android Bundling failed 11952ms node_modules/expo-router/entry.js (1923 modules)
Unable to resolve "@/assets/converted_model/group1-shard1of1.bin" from "app/(MyApp)/Artikel/PrediksiHama.tsx"
edit: im using tensorflow/tfjs and tensorflow/tfjs-react-native
i am getting this error, i tried to create a metro.config.js file with bin inside the resolver but it doesn't work
i want to implement my tensorflow model in my react native apps. my model is to predict temperature, humidity and more.
